# Apply lubridate::ymd() to all columns with "date" in name

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, stringr

I'm importing several csv files and upon import want to apply lubridate::ymd() to all columns that have "date" in their name.  I get error with the following.  Appreciate the help.

```
    client <- read.csv("client.csv") %>% 
       mutate(across(str_detect(., "date")), ymd())
```

I get the following error:

Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `..1`.
i `..1 = across(str_detect(., "date"))`.
x Must subset columns with a valid subscript vector.
x Subscript has the wrong type `logical`.
i It must be numeric or character.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
In addition: Warning message:
Problem with `mutate()` input `..1`.
i `..1 = across(str_detect(., "date"))`.
i argument is not an atomic vector; coercing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use tidyselect functions to select columns in `across`. To apply a function which has a particular word in them you can use `contains` or `matches`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

client <- read.csv("client.csv") %>% mutate(across(contains('date'), ymd))
#Using matches
#client <- read.csv("client.csv") %>% mutate(across(matches('date'), ymd))
```

Answer (score 2):

If we want to invoke the function, use a lamdba function (`~`) which would also give more control and flexibility in terms of specifying different arguments

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
client <- read.csv("client.csv") %>%
             mutate(across(contains("date"), ~ ymd(.)))
```

Comment: is there another way using data table? @akrun